# Multiple embedded fonts in final PDF

Tags: fonts, xetex, embedding

I am using XeLaTeX with PDFs incorporated. Each PDF has its fonts embedded and my final output therefore has fonts embedded multiple times which, presumably, increases the file size.

Is there a way to combine the fonts to a single embedding instance?

Comment: Does the size really matter that much? I have PDFs over 50MiB in size of which most is pictures. Fonts make up only insignificant portion of the whole file.

Comment: I have found in the past that files with fonts embedded multiple times dramatically increased the file size. Outputting as PS then using Distiller to embed just once reduced file size from over 10MB to 500kB (this was MS Word). But it's more a matter of efficiency. I'd rather have a task completed once rather than multiple times over.